# How to make a "Springy curve" in Flutter for a button scale effect?

Tags: animation, dart, transition, flutter, curve

I'm trying to make a pleasing "spring" effect to scale a button and other components. In particular I want to scale them in when the view is created and shown, and I want to scale them down when a user taps a button, and if the user releases the button, I want them to scale back up to normal size with the spring effect.

The Facebook library "rebound" is a perfect example, see their demo here: https://facebook.github.io/rebound/.

I tried all the built in curves like bounceIn/Out and elasticIn/Out but they weren't springy enough (elastic is kind of springy).

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: check this answer using CurvedAnimation and Curves.bounceOut: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364049/how-do-you-add-a-curves-class-animation-to-animationcontroller-in-flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Remi said, you can use the `Curve` class and override the transform method.

The difficult part is then figuring out the formula to use. I'd play around with something like this [curve calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6gbvrm5i0s) to get a formula.

i.e. `-(e^(-x/a) * cos(xw)) + 1` with `a = 0.15` and `w = 19.4`.

Another alternative is to use existing curves together - since they all start at 0 and end at 1, you can simply multiply two different curves together in your overloaded curve method.

I'd take a look at the implementation of ElasticIn and ElasticOut to figure out how they did the math, but the dart math library should have everything you need.

Comment: Thanks! That website is a great resource and that formula works!

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never:

you may find the package https://pub.dev/packages/sprung useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `Curve` by overriding `transform`.

As long a `mycurve.transform(0) == 0` and `mycurve.transform(1) == 1` you can do pretty much anything.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but in my case I really can't work out the math behind reproducing the spring effect. I was looking for some help with that.

Comment: We can't give you a formula here. As it's opinion-based. Find an existing one and port it.