# How do you add a Curves class animation to AnimationController in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-animation

I'm trying to add the curves class animation 'Curves.bounceOut' to my code that uses an AnimationController.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  var squareScale = 1.0;
  static AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        lowerBound: 0.5,
        upperBound: 1.0,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));

    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        squareScale = _controller.value;
      });
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Bounce Example"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 150.0,
            height: 150.0,
            color: Colors.yellowAccent,
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
                    },
                    child: Transform.scale(
                      scale: squareScale,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 150.0,
                        height: 150.0,
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Currently the green container animates from 0.5 scale to 1.0 scale but does not bounce. How can I add the 'Curves.bounceOut' animation so the container bounces when tapped?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: see `CurvedAnimation`

Comment: I have seen the CurvedAnimation class but I can't figure out how to properly include it in my code.

Comment: instead of `_controller.addListener` use `_curvedAnimation.addListener` ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You'll want to use both an animation controller and a tween, which will allow you to add `Curves.bounceOut`.

Somewhere in your code add:

```dart
AnimationController _controller;
var scaleAnimation;
```

And in your `initState()` method:

```dart
_controller = new AnimationController(
 duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 300),
 vsync: this
)
..addListener(() {
  setState(() {});
});
scaleAnimation = new Tween(
  begin: 0.5,
  end: 1.0,
).animate(new CurvedAnimation(
  parent: _controller,
  curve: Curves.bounceOut
));
```

Note the `..addListener()` is a nice bit of dart code that allows you to add a listener easily. The Tween is basically telling your animation that it needs to go from the value in `begin` to the value in `end` within the timeframe given in the `AnimationController`. To use this value in your code you can now just set the scale of your result of your animation:

```dart
child: Transform.scale(
  scale: scaleAnimation.value,
  child: Container(
    width: 150.0,
    height: 150.0,
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
),
```

And when the animation is called it will then automatically update the scale of the container.

Edit:

Change your widget to this:

```dart
child: isChanging ? Transform.scale(
  scale: scaleAnimation.value,
  child: Container(
    width: 150.0,
    height: 150.0,
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
) : Transform.scale(
  scale: 1.0,
  child: Container(
    width: 150.0,
    height: 150.0,
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
),
```

Keep your `begin` and `end` parameters as `0.5` and `1.0` respectively, but in your `onTap()` method before you forward your controller add:

```dart
onTap: () {
  setState(() {
    isChanging = true
  });
  _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
}
```

And anywhere in your code add the line `bool isChanging`. Finally you'll want to reset the shown widget at the end of your animation, so change your scaleAnimation to:

```dart
child: Transform.scale(
  scale: scaleAnimation.value,
  child: Container(
    width: 150.0,
    height: 150.0,
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
)..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) {
  if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) { //the animation is finished
    _controller.reset();
    setState(() {
      isChanging = false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! Do you know how I can have the container start at a width of 150.0 by 150.0 before any animation has been triggered? Right now it starts at a scale of 0.5, not 1.0.

Comment: You could swap the `begin` and `end` parameters within the `scaleAnimation`. This would make the scale start at `1.0` and get smaller and bigger. Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry I must not have been clear enough. I want the animation to go from the scale of 0.5 to 1.0 every time the container is tapped. However when the app is first launched the container starts at a scale of 0.5, I want it to start at a scale of 1.0 and then when tapped jump straight to scale 0.5 and animate up to scale 1.0. Is this possible? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @hello_friend It might be possible.... you would have to set *both* the `begin` and `end` parameters to 1.0, and then have your curve be part of a `sin(x)` curve. Even then, however, the animation would not jump from being at 1.0 to being at 0.5 instantly. Potentially you could have a conditional statement where the widget is, where if a boolean is true then it display a 1.0 scale of the container, then when you click the button it would set it to false, changing the widget to a widget of scale 0.5 and then run the animation on that widget. Let me know if you need me to add that to my answer.

Comment: That would be great if you added this to your answer.

Answer (score 13):

A more succinct way to do this is to just use `controller.drive()` and `CurveTween`:

```
anim = animController.drive(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeOut));
```

Then use `anim.value` in your widget tree.

Can also do this inline if you want:

```
Opacity(opacity: controller.drive(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeOut)).value)
```